# MySQL: Invalid JSON path expression

Tags: mysql, json, select, mysql-8.0, json-extract

i have json like this:

```
[
     {
         "id": "id1",
         "value": 1
     },
     {
         "id": "id2",
         "value": 197
     },
     ...
]
```

and i want extract "value" by "id", so i try this:

`select JSON_EXTRACT(@structure_json, "$[?(@.id=='id2')].value")`
and i got:

> SQL Error (3143): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 2.

whats going on?

Comment: Such reference not supported in MySQL.

Comment: Parse and analyze. See https://dbfiddle.uk/JfEDsfk0